# Android - Adding item to array.xml with String[] Array

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am trying now for days to add item (String) into `array.xml` (string-array) file in values folder. The added item must be stored there, because i want to use this strings in another activity, too.

my *array.xml* looks like this

```
<string-array name="Array">
    <item>Example</item>
</string-array>
```

I have tried it in different ways, but as the last it looks in my *MainActivity* like this

```
private void addArray(){
    String [] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Array);
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
    adapter.add("Hello");
}
```

But that did not work either. This don't adds an item to my `array.xml` file.

Comment: asked bazillion times, resoures are read only

Comment: Yes, I know, but I read all bazillion posts. And found this solution, but this dont works.

Comment: Lol, it is not a solution for adding to `array.xml` resource... because you can't do this at all ... what do you not understand in **READ ONLY** ?